# Menu not appearing in VSCode app [ed] 0.10.3 Linux Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

When I launch the Code application from either the command line or Launcher, VS Studio Code runs but the menu bar (File, Edit, View...) is missing. I had a similar problem with Eclipse, and the canonical answer appears to be setting a magic environment variable UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0. But this guess doesn't seem to work. Anyone else seeing this problem? Fix?

Comment: Why are you using 0.6.0, that is a very outdated old version?

Comment: @Ken, you'll want to update to the latest version. Your issue should be fixed.

Comment: Apologies; I am running the latest (I was confusing the web starter toolkit version, duh). I now just realized even the VS Code [screenshot](https://code.visualstudio.com/Content/images/hero-linux.png) at https://code.visualstudio.com/ when viewed from a Ubuntu host is missing the menu. Is the menu supposed to be missing from Linux hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now VS Code officially tested in Ubuntu 14.04 check here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements. But feature releases will be supported as I have tested the insider release which gives some promising here.

> For now you can install March's Insider release (thanks to the `.deb`
>   packages) from here https://code.visualstudio.com/Download#insiders
>   where those bugs for 15.10 has been fixed.

If you want to install stable version wait until April 14, the version 1.0 will be released https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs#_10-release